# Height of box ignore child padding box

Tags: css

I have a problem with padding and container.

```css
.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

a {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <span class="link">
        <a href="#"><span>Hello!</span></a>
    </span>
</div>
```

When a content has a padding the container ignores the padding's height.
In the example is visible that the span "link" is not drawn in the edge of the container.

How can I fix the problem?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxjwcdyp/3/)

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Paulie, this is my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rxjwcdyp/5/

Comment: To obtain best solution for my problem I prefer `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

since the a is an inline-element, you have to give it a display:block.
Maybe you watch some tutorials about how HTML-elements work!